# Iterate through JSON in Scala

Tags: json, scala, seq

sorry if it's a basic question.
When I'm running the following code to print testRegJs:

```
val testRegJs: Seq[JsValue] = for (tr <- testReg) yield Json.toJson(tr)
```

Note: here testReg is list of certain criteria i.e sequence of object and in the above code it is converted to seq[JsValue].

Output:

```
List({
"registration": {
    "id": 495,
    "profile_id": "755"
},
"test_center": [{
    "id": 487,
    "registration_id": 495
}]
}, {
"registration": {
    "id": 599,
    "profile_id": "360"
},
"test_center": [{
    "id": 594,
    "registration_id": 599
}]
})
```

I want to print **id** from the above list. How it can be done?

Comment: Please tell us/tag the JSON library you are using in Scala, as they are all different.

Comment: play.api.libs.json._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following line to get the desired output:

```
val regId = testRegJs.map(x => (x \ "registration" \ "id").as[Int])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `testRegJs \\ "id"` for getting the id.

Comment: @shivani can you please verify the above solution?

Comment: not working that way. It says cannot  find the symbol "\\".

Comment: [play JSON recursive path](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson#Recursive-path-\\), please look the example which is given here.

Comment: yes i also tried it this way earlier referring same documentation but it was not working in my code. Don't know the reason. @anurag